# Inconsistency in Flurry debug logging

Tags: android, flurry

I am using version 3.2.0 of the Flurry Android SDK.

I have turned on logging - the results of which are shown below. I have
created a timed event called **'ShowingDownloadDirector'** which times the
duration a particular dialog is shown.

The following is the output (see section (1) below) after hitting a retry button. The time between
each retry is less then one second - but the duration being logged suggest
a significantly longer duration?

I have confirmed that the start/end events are aligned - there is an end
event for each start event. I thought maybe the events where from the start
of the app, but there are later entries that have a lower value then
previous entries.

I am also seeing that subsequent events are not getting logged. See section (2) below of my event trace. In the debug output from the device generated by your SDK, it only shows the logging once of an event.

Any subsequent logging does not generate any debug output.

Can you explain? Is this a limitation of Flurry, or of Flurry's debug output?

Where is the data stored locally on the device so that I can confirm that it is in fact logging the correct thing?

BTW - Please do not ask me about the server. The issue here is NOT the server. The issue here is with what your SDK is reporting locally on the device when I issue log requests. I just need to understand the inconsistency.

Thanks,
Tim

**Section 1**

```
D/FlurryAgent( 4663): Ended event 'ShowingDownloadDirector' (524144) after 1367ms
D/FlurryAgent( 4663): Ended event 'ShowingDownloadDirector' (535617) after 444ms
D/FlurryAgent( 4663): Ended event 'ShowingDownloadDirector' (535774) after 1900ms
D/FlurryAgent( 4663): Ended event 'ShowingDownloadDirector' (537189) after 7702ms
D/FlurryAgent( 4663): Ended event 'ShowingDownloadDirector' (537415) after 13942ms
D/FlurryAgent( 4663): Ended event 'ShowingDownloadDirector' (544448) after 9241ms
```

**Section 2**

```
E/RMS (10264): Error Unity 07/15/2013 12:31:17 LOGGING startup
D/FlurryAgent(10264): Error logged: EventLoggerAndroid.LogEvent
D/FlurryAgent(10264): Event count incremented: startup
E/RMS (10264): Error Unity 07/15/2013 12:31:40 LOGGING PurchaseStarted
D/FlurryAgent(10264): Event count incremented: PurchaseStarted
E/RMS (10264): Error Unity 07/15/2013 12:31:44 LOGGING PurchaseCanceled
D/FlurryAgent(10264): Event count incremented: PurchaseCanceled
E/RMS (10264): Error Unity 07/15/2013 12:31:55 LOGGING PurchaseStarted
<-- NO Flurry log here ??? -->
E/RMS (10264): Error Unity 07/15/2013 12:32:06 LOGGING PurchaseCanceled
<-- NO Flurry logging here ??? -->
```